# Getting value from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$rates`

I used `print_r` to see if I have the values I want. And returns the information below.

```
Array (
    [125] => Array (
        [2011] => Array (
            [ca] => Array (
                [8810] => Array (
                    [0] => Array (
                      [Key] => 481
                      [Code] => 8810
                      [Desc] => Clerical Office Employees - NOC
                      [Desc_escaped] => Clerical Office Employees - NOC
                      [Rate] => 0.82
                      [Exclusion] => 0
                      [peo_id] =>
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I have tried a number of methods to get the info I want but have been unsuccessful.  I am after the value of [Rate]

Comment: I assume that the indexes can change, but for this one it is `$rates[125][2011]['ca'][8810][0]['Rate']`.  If those numbers (other than the 0) are meaningful then it should be easy to get from others.

Comment: Do you even try this? `$rates['125']['2011']['ca']['8810']['0']['Rate']`

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to get it when the indexes do change?

Comment: I tried this $rates[$q_peo_id][$rate_year][$state]['Rate']

Comment: If those vars are correct then you are missing one var (8810) and a 0:  `$rates[$q_peo_id][$rate_year][$state][8810][0]['Rate']`.  So where does 8810 come from?

Comment: @AbraCadaver  
Nailed it... Thanks $rates[$q_peo_id][$rate_year][$state][$scopes_code][0]['Rate']  worked perfectly.  I left out one $scopes_code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$rates[125][2011]['ca'][8810][0]['Rate'];
```